# primefaces lazy data loading and hibernate, java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf-2, primefaces

I followed the example of the page of primefaces (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf), and it worked but because the example is loading the list on the constructor it is no exactly lazy loading.  I understand that is a dummy example, so on my bean I added this lines

```
private LazyDataModel<Ficha> lazyListFichas;
```

And my init funcion I changed some parts to this

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Inicializando fichas");
        tienePadres=false;
        fichaDM.setFicha(new Ficha());
        //obtenerFichas();
        //lazyListFichas = new FichaLazyList(fichaDM.getFichas);
        lazyListFichas = new FichaLazyList();

    }
```

My FichaLazyList is like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;
import org.primefaces.model.SortOrder;

import ec.edu.puce.biologia.dao.FichaDao;
import ec.edu.puce.biologia.util.LazySorter;


@ViewScoped
public class FichaLazyList extends LazyDataModel <Ficha> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Ficha> fichas=new ArrayList<Ficha>();

    @EJB
    private FichaDao fichaDao;

    public FichaLazyList() {  
    }  

    public FichaLazyList(List<Ficha> fichas) {  
        this.fichas = fichas;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public Ficha getRowData(String rowKey) {  
        for(Ficha ficha : fichas) {  
            if(ficha.getIdFicha().equals(rowKey))  
                return ficha;  
        }  

        return null;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public Object getRowKey(Ficha ficha) {  
        return ficha.getIdFicha(); 
    }  

    @Override  
    public List<Ficha> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {  
        List<Ficha> data = new ArrayList<Ficha>();  

      //filter 
        fichas = fichaDao.encontrarPagina(first, pageSize);
        if(fichas==null){
            System.out.println("Lista nula");
        }
        for(Ficha ficha : fichas) {  
            boolean match = true;  

            for(Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {  
                try {  
                    String filterProperty = it.next();  
                    String filterValue = filters.get(filterProperty);  
                    String fieldValue = String.valueOf(ficha.getClass().getField(filterProperty).get(ficha));  

                    if(filterValue == null || fieldValue.startsWith(filterValue)) {  
                        match = true;  
                    }  
                    else {  
                        match = false;  
                        break;  
                    }  
                } catch(Exception e) {  
                    match = false;  
                }   
            }  

            if(match) {  
                data.add(ficha);  
            }  
        }


        long total = fichaDao.contar();
        System.out.println("xxx"+total);

        //sort  
        if(sortField != null) {  
            Collections.sort(data, new LazySorter(sortField, sortOrder));  
        }  

        //rowCount  
       // int dataSize = data.size();  
        this.setRowCount((int) total);  

        //paginate  
        if(total > pageSize) {  
            try {  
                return data.subList(first, first + pageSize);  
            }  
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {  
                return data.subList(first, first + ((int) total % pageSize));  
            }  
        }  
        else {  
            return data;  
        }  
    }

    public List<Ficha> getFichas() {
        return fichas;
    }

    public void setFichas(List<Ficha> fichas) {
        this.fichas = fichas;
    }


}
```

I get this error,

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/catalogoBiologia].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ec.edu.puce.biologia.model.FichaLazyList.load(FichaLazyList.java:55) [classes:]
```

Line 55 is this

```
fichas = fichaDao.encontrarPagina(first, pageSize);
```

Should it be viewscope or session scope, What am I doing wrong when I try to inject the ejb

Comment: How are you managing your beans? There's nowhere a `@ManagedBean`, `@Named` or like. Are you manually constructing it using `new` operator or what? Or are you using a 3rd party and EJB-incompatible framework like Spring to manage it?

Comment: I am just using hibernate, using a the persistence.xml configuration, with jboss, my jboss has PersistenceUinit and a datasource.  My TaxonomiaController is the @ManagedBean. I just added the code.

Comment: Hibernate is an ORM framework, not a bean management framework (like JSF, CDI, Seam, Spring, etc), so I'm not sure how's that relevant to my comment. The newly added code only adds more confusion. It's a completely different class and does not match the problem as shown in the stack trace. Please re-read your question from top to bottom and fix/clarify it accordingly. Do not add more and more questions, instead improve the initial question. You're obligated to remove irrelevant parts from the question.

Comment: How are you managing the `FichaLazyList` bean? So far now it look like that you're manually constructing it by `new FichaLazyList()`. Obviously, `@EJB` won't work as you're not manually setting it after the manual construction. The `@EJB` injection works only in managed beans, otherwise you've to manually grab the EJB instance from JNDI and set it as instance variable. Your `FichaLazyList` has to be a managed bean some way in order to get `@EJB` to work.

Comment: I am an Idiot, I see the errors I had.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks Balusc, I was only calling it in my function with new.  I changed value="#{taxonomiaController.lazyListFichas}"  from my datatable to value="#{fichaLazyList}", In my head I didnt see FichaLazyList as a bean, it was another class, anyways that solved the problem and, I added @ManagedBean and @RequestScoped to FichaLazyList I guess it could be also @viewScoped. It seemed to me that should be RequestedScoped, if not I ll fix this.
Also I added this to the init function, it is another approach using an anoymous class:

lazyListFichas = new LazyDataModel() {
            @Override
            public List load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map filters){

```
            List<Ficha> lazyFicha = new ArrayList<Ficha>();
            lazyFicha = servicioFicha.obtenerTodos(first, pageSize);
            // populateLazyRandomCars(lazyFicha, pageSize);

            return lazyFicha;
        }
    };

    /**
     * In a real application, this number should be resolved by a projection
     * query
     */
    lazyListFichas.setRowCount((int) servicioFicha.contarRegistrosTotal());
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is not in your managed bean,the problem is in your model EJB or Hibernate
because the value of fichas is null so fichaDao.encontrarPagina(first, pageSize) returns null check the code of fichaDao and your hibernate settings to connect to database.

Comment: shouldnt it be like a @requestscope, my settings are correct, I am doing many other CRUD operations and they work, here is the only problem I have.  Before something like this happened to me with a converter, and I used requestescope and it worked. A friend of mine told me to use Statefull or Stateless.

Comment: The information provided so far clearly confirms that `fichaDao` is by itself `null`. In other words, `@EJB` didn't do its job at all. In other words, the bean instance is been created in a way which didn't take `@EJB` injection into account. For example, when it's manually been instantiated using `new` or been managed by e.g. Spring instead of JSF itself.